# VB.Net: If Statement While Conditional Formatting

Tags: excel, formula, conditional-formatting

I'm trying to use an if statement in my conditional formatting example. I have been able to successfully use conditional formatting, but am having issues figuring out how to incorporate an `if` statement in it. The if statement is...

```
IF cell I2 is not empty AND cell b2 < 1 mark the cell red.
```

`IF (AND(I2 <> "", B2 < 1), Red?, not red?)`

I feel like I have two pieces of the puzzle here, but not sure how to put them together.

Conditional formatting code:

```
protoWorksheet.Range("E2:E100").FormatConditions.Add(XlFormatConditionType.xlExpression, Type.Missing, "=E2=""Gap""").Interior.Color = RGB(255, 0, 0)
```

Comment: If you're just doing a conditional format formula, you don't need the `IF()` part. You could just set the formula to `=AND($I2<>"",$B2<1)`  Only when both parts resolve to `TRUE` will the conditional format apply.

Comment: @BruceWayne i'm getting a "parameter is incorrect" error using `        protoWorksheet.Range("B2:B100").FormatConditions.Add(XlFormatConditionType.xlExpression, Type.Missing, "=AND(I2<>"",B2<1)").Interior.Color = RGB(255, 51, 51)
` I have tried both with and without the dollar signs

Comment: for the O2<>blank try `I2<>""""` (four quotes instead of two)

Comment: @Brucewayne damn double quotes always get me... worked like a charm. throw an answer up!

Comment: If this is VBA you have the wring tag - VBA IsNot VB.NET

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When using a formula in VBA, if you want to use double quotes, you have to double up:

`"=AND($I2<>"""",B2<1)"`

Otherwise, VBA will read to the second single quote, and stop reading as a formula, so anything after that will likely throw an error.

If you wanted to include some text, it'd be: `"=AND($I2=""My Words"",B2<1)"` for example.